# How to remove the hole MediaLibrary Tab from Media Uploader in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, media

I created a custom button for uploading images to wordpress media. How to hide the hole "mediaLibrary" Section in the Media Upload Modal?. I tried the following code which only removes the tab title not the hole tab. There are a lot of answers claiming that the following removes the tab - but it only removes the tab title. **Any idea how to solve this issue?**

Following code only removes the tab title

```
function remove_medialibrary_tab($tabs) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
       unset($tabs["mediaLibraryTitle"]);
    }
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_view_strings', 'remove_medialibrary_tab');
```

Some visual to make it clear for everyone

**Remove the following section**

[image]

**Keep the following section**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a support feature plugin where the user is only allowed to upload media to custom post.  The attached media will then be displayed in a metabox along with a button that opens the media uploader.  So, I have the same problem:  I only want the "Upload files" tab and no ability to select existing media via the "Media Library" tab.

First, I don't have to do any extra work to attach the file to the post provided I pass the post ID during `admin_enqueue_scripts` enqueuing of the media library:

```
wp_enqueue_media(array(
    'post'  => isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : NULL,
));
```

Second, I attach a listener to the media library on it's opening to hide the "Media Library" tab and to activate the "Upload files" tab and display its contents (this is javascript that acts on the object created by `wp.media({})`):

```
my_frame.on('open', function(){
    jQuery(".media-menu-item#menu-item-browse").hide();
    jQuery(".media-menu-item#menu-item-upload").trigger('click');
});
```

Lastly, when the user uploads a file, the Media Uploader displays the "Media Library" content and awaits the user to select that media.  The point is to hide the "Media Library" content so displaying it after upload completely defeats the purpose.  When I first read this answer over a week ago, I had no idea what to do.  Today, I ran across a freakishly weird javascript trigger that is called `{region}:activate:{mode}` (yeah, I know).

```
my_frame.on('content:activate:browse', function(){
    my_frame.close();
});
```

The "content" region is the main viewport under the tabs.  When that region changes, it go through a series of triggers (one being "activate").  The stuff displayed in the viewport is the mode:  "browse" is the mode for the "Media Library" tab; and "upload" is the mode for the "Upload files" tab).  And, that's how the trigger fired when the content of the Media Library is displayed gets its name (`content:activate:browse`).

Answer (score 0):

When you switching to media library tab, starts ajax query for load attachments. You can try add this action with 1 priority.

```
function restrict_non_Admins(){
    if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_query-attachments', 'restrict_non_Admins', 1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_query-attachments', 'restrict_non_Admins', 1);
```

Also you can hide tab with css or remove html with js.